# Can I manipulate the DOM based on each item in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to randomize all elements in an array and assign it a value of true or false. (which works) Then based on the new array I want to show an image for items that equals true and hide all images that equals false.

```
let pinNumbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"];



let randomNumber = () => {
  num = 
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  if(num === 0) {
    return true;
  }else {
    return false;
  }

}

let pinNumber = pinNumbers.map (function () {
return randomNumber();
});

let showPin = pinNumber.forEach (function (item) {
  if (item === true) {
    return document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "visible";
  }else {
    return document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
});
```

Comment: You are accessing `”one”` on each iteration, I guess you should make your `item` iterate the `pinNumbers` array, then call your random function, and change the visibility for the given `item` based on the result. One `.forEach` would be enough to do that. If you need two arrays, use the regular `for` loop with an index.

Comment: Thanks @afenster This was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `forEach` add the index, and take the pinNumbers[index]:

```
let showPin = pinNumber.forEach(function (item, index) {
    if (item === true) {
    return document.getElementById(pinNumbers[index]).style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        return document.getElementById(pinNumbers[index]).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
});
```

Comment: I changed it to

`
let showPin = pinNumbers.forEach (function (item) {
if (randomNumber() === true) {
    return document.getElementById(item).style.visibility = "visible";
  }else {
    return document.getElementById(item).style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
});
`

Comment: O.K, is will work, but you need to know that you can send the index of the current iteration in `forEach`.

Comment: By the way, you write `randomNumber` functionshorter: let randomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0 ;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 you can achieve this using below code.

```
 for (const [i, value] of pinNumbers.entries()) {
       if(value){
       document.getElementById(pinNumbers[i]).style.visibility = "visible";
       }else{
       document.getElementById(pinNumbers[i]).style.visibility = "visible";
       }
    }
```